# Python folium problem with editing draw plugin

Tags: python, folium

I would like to make some edits to the Python Folium.draw plugin.

I have the code from the following link:

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/folium/plugins/draw.py

After applying it to my code I have an error:

**if self.export:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined**

```
 def __init__(
    self,
    export=False,
    filename="data.geojson",
    position="topleft",
    show_geometry_on_click=True,
    draw_options=None,
    edit_options=None,
   ):
    super().__init__()
    self._name = "DrawControl"
    self.export = export
    self.filename = filename
    self.position = position
    self.show_geometry_on_click = show_geometry_on_click
    self.draw_options = draw_options or {}
    self.edit_options = edit_options or {}

  def render(self, **kwargs):
    super().render(**kwargs)

    figure = self.get_root()
    assert isinstance(
        figure, Figure
     ), "You cannot render this Element if it is not in a Figure."

    export_style = """
        <style>
            #export {
                position: absolute;
                top: 5px;
                right: 10px;
                z-index: 999;
                background: white;
                color: black;
                padding: 6px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
                cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-decoration: none;
                top: 90px;
            }
         </style>
      """
    export_button = """<a href='#' id='export'>Export</a>"""

    if self.export:
        figure.header.add_child(Element(export_style), name="export")
        figure.html.add_child(Element(export_button), name="export_button")
```

I see that self has been defined already.

What exactly causes this error and how to fix it?

Comment: probably indentation ...

Comment: I have nothing indicated as the indentation could be wrong. Let me edit the code as it looks with indentation.

Comment: please include the full traceback ... and try running it with `python -t my_script.py` which should warn you about inconsistent indentation ... with proper indentation self should definitely exist

Comment: I couldn't find proper codepen for Python, but have a look at my whole code here:

https://codepen.io/Kruku/pen/ZERxprq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal working example:

```py
import folium
from branca.element import Element, Figure, MacroElement
from jinja2 import Template
from folium.elements import JSCSSMixin


class Draw(JSCSSMixin, MacroElement):
    def __init__(
        self,
        export=False,
        filename="data.geojson",
        position="topleft",
        show_geometry_on_click=True,
        draw_options=None,
        edit_options=None,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = "DrawControl"
        self.export = export
        self.filename = filename
        self.position = position
        self.show_geometry_on_click = show_geometry_on_click
        self.draw_options = draw_options or {}
        self.edit_options = edit_options or {}

    def render(self, **kwargs):
        super().render(**kwargs)

        figure = self.get_root()
        assert isinstance(
            figure, Figure
        ), "You cannot render this Element if it is not in a Figure."

        export_style = """
            <style>
                #export {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 5px;
                    right: 10px;
                    z-index: 999;
                    background: white;
                    color: black;
                    padding: 6px;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
                    cursor: pointer;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    top: 90px;
                }
            </style>
        """
        export_button = """<a href='#' id='export'>Export</a>"""
        if self.export:
            figure.header.add_child(Element(export_style), name="export")
            figure.html.add_child(Element(export_button), name="export_button")

            
m = folium.Map(location=[38,35], zoom_start=10)
draw = Draw(export=True)
draw.add_to(m)

m
```

Then, you can edit class `Draw` as you desire.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I had a too small an indentation in my code :) Thank you so much!